# Using or reusing Wagtail StreamField blocks as Fields in other models

Tags: python, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I have a Wagtail project with two different `Page` models that use identical gallery blocks, but in different ways. In one model, I want to use the gallery in a list of other freeform blocks; but in the other model there is only one gallery appearing in a specific place on the page. The galleries are pretty complex, with lots of options like `autoadvance` that I don’t want to repeat between models, and which aren’t easy to move into a mixin. I can accomplish what I want by adding an extra `gallery` StreamField to the strict model, like this: *(`content_panel` etc. omitted)*

```py
# models.py
from wagtail.models import Page
from wagtail.core.fields import RichTextField, StreamField
from wagtail.images.blocks import ImageChooserBlock
from wagtail.core.blocks import (
    RichTextBlock, 
    StructBlock, 
    StreamBlock,
)

class ImageWithCaptionBlock(StructBlock):
    image = ImageChooserBlock()
    caption = RichTextBlock()


class GalleryBlock(StructBlock):
    # lots of gallery options like “autoadvance”
    items = StreamBlock([
        ('image', ImageWithCaptionBlock()),
        ('video', EmbedBlock()),
    ])    


class FreeFormContentPage(Page):
    body = StreamField([
        ('richtext', RichTextBlock()),
        ('gallery', GalleryBlock()),
    ], use_json_field=True)


class StrictContentPage(Page):
    body = RichTextField()
    gallery = StreamField([
         ('gallery', GalleryBlock()),
    ], use_json_field=True, max_num=1)
```

This works but it looks a little weird when editing a `StrictContentPage`!

[image: screenshot of wagtail admin UI showing nested “Gallery” elements]

What I’m looking to do is something like this:

```py
class StrictContentPage(Page):
    body = RichTextField()
    gallery = GalleryBlock()
```

(or the equivalent via tweaking the admin)

… so that the admin experience looks like:

[image: screenshot of Wagtail admin UI showing one “Gallery” element with an imageblock]

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Answer (score 1):

If you still need this, I would approach it with the mindset of creating a variable for the content that's inside the `StreamBlock`/`StreamField`.

Consider the following example:

```py
class ImageWithCaptionBlock(StructBlock):
    image = ImageChooserBlock()
    caption = RichTextBlock()

GALLERY_BLOCKS = [
    ('image', ImageWithCaptionBlock()),
    ('video', EmbedBlock()),
]

class GalleryBlock(StructBlock):
    # lots of gallery options like “autoadvance”
    items = StreamBlock(GALLERY_BLOCKS)    

class FreeFormContentPage(Page):
    body = StreamField([
        ('richtext', RichTextBlock()),
        ('gallery', GalleryBlock()),
    ], use_json_field=True)

class StrictContentPage(Page):
    body = RichTextField()
    gallery = StreamField(GALLERY_BLOCKS, use_json_field=True)
```

This approach will make the UI more readable for the `StrictContentPage` page version and maintain the same user experience for the `FreeFormContentPage` version. Plus, you won't need redundant code to change the fields for the different page types.

I hope this will help you out. Have a great day!